# Regression with percentage change?

Tags: regression, self-study, percentage

> As the education rating of a Canadian city decreases by $1\%$, the crime rating will change by ___ (make sure you include the negative sign if warranted)

The line of the equation I found to be $\hat{y}= 81.926 - 1.968x$ and the correlation coefficient I found to be $-0.816$. I'm stumped on what to do next.

The x values are the Education Rating % in Canadian cities - `35, 35, 31, 32, 30, 36, 33`

The y values are the Crime Rating % - `12, 10, 16, 20, 25, 13, 21`

I have no idea how to calculate the decrease of $1\%$.

Do I have to redo all the calculations with $1$ subtracted from the $x$ values? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: (1) you may want to add self-study tag (2) is linear regression appropriate for percentage data?(3) when specifying a % decrease - and you're x-value is a percentage - you may want to make clear whether absolute or relative change (4) why not just plug in some numbers and see? this question can be solved by understanding the equation or just plugging in numbers.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) to see how such questions are dealt with here. (It's possible you may need to slightly modify your question to fit the guidelines there.)

Comment: Thank you for the edit help. The first few parts of the question were solved by me already. I found the regression line equation and correlation coefficient. But for this part do you mean decrease each x value by 1 and plug into the regression equation?

Comment: Putting x=1 you get y=79.96 and that should be the change with every 1% change in x (since x is in percent to start with).